# How can I associate repository with folder

Tags: svn

Some time ago I have done checkout repository. Also I have written username and password. Now I have changed Ubuntu and cannot do commit. I have done checkout but it don't ask my username and password. I only usual user and do not have access to repository. How I can login in the repository to do commit? Bash says svn mydir is not under version control.

Answer (score 0):

When you upgraded your Ubuntu maybe SVN was also upgraded to a newer major version. Then you have to use the [svn upgrade](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.upgrade.html) command.

Another possibility would be, that your `.svn` folder in the working copy root folder has been deleted or is corrupted. Then checkout a new working copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tortovise Svn as client you can do it by clearing authentication cache from it.

Under Settings > Saved Data > Clear Authentication Data.

Jyotsna